# iOS Storyboard How to access the controls and add event handlers, and binding data to controls added on Storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios5, interface-builder, storyboard, ios

I used to create the UI thru code. But now I have to use storyboard. I am confused about how to add the event handlers to the controls added on the storyboard and how to bind the data dynamically to the controls added on storyboard. A sample scenario is An UIView is added on the storyboard and two UITableViews and a button are added on top of it.  I want to add event handler to the button and bind data to the table views. How do I do this. If I subclass the UIView added on the storyboard will I have access to the controls(button, two table views) added on top of the view or how else I should achieve this ?. Please help !

Answer (score 9):

Adding an event handler to a button is relatively simple. In your UIViewController subclass simply add a method similar to the one below, then in your interface builder select the viewcontroller and on the right side panel click the right most button at the top which looks like an arrow pointing to the right. under received actions drag the circle to the button that you want to perform the action.

```
-(IBAction)doSomething:(id)sender{
    //code for doing what you want your button to do.
}
```

A separate way you could do it, if you still want to do it programatically is to do the same thing you're used to doing, except in your .h file add IBOutlet UIButton *buttonName; and in the right pane under outlets you'll see your button. which can then be referenced by name within the .m file.